# .htaccess rewrite. subdomain map to query string

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way to use htaccess to silently append ?lang= to whatever url is being viewed?

I have multiple subdomains (e.g. pl.example.com, es.example.com, etc) and they all point to example.com.

I wish them to point to example.com?lang=pl, example.com?lang=es, etc. But they must preserve the paths. so if you visit "pl.example.com/users/settings" in the background the request would be to "example.com/users/settings?lang=pl"

I hope this makes sense. I would appreciate any and all help you can give me as I have been stuck on this problem for a while. I don't wish to redirect the page to ?lang=, only silently append it to the current request.

Comment: Please show your current .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Something like that probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=%1 [QSA,END]
```

This obviously requires the rewriting module to be loaded and activated. You should implement such rules in the actual host configuration of your http server. If you have no access to that (so if you are using a cheap hosting provider) you can use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but that needs to be enabled in the server and those files create a performance penalty.